# I want to use Google authentication but I got 400 error:Invalid_request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, redirect, oauth

I develop using ASP.NET MVC 5.
And I added Google Authentication to my project. (OAuth)

First of all, I set to google develop console:
Original Javascript : http://localhost/
Redirection URL     : http://localhost/signin-google
And It worked well.

Then for the test, I deposit project to my office private network.
There is virtual directory 'test231' and had 3 area(aa,bb,cc).
And all of 3 area want to use google authentication.

So I try to add to google develop console many ways:

> 1. Original Javascript(Fail) : http://test231/aa/(or bb, cc)
> 2. Original Javascript : http://test231/
>
>    (1) Redirection URL(Fail)     : http://test231/signin-google
>
>    (2) Redirection URL(Fail)     : http://test231/aa/signin-google

All cases are got the 'ERROR'.

> **Error: invalid_request**
>
> **Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://test231/aa/signin-google**

There are no differences between localhost and test231.

How Can I use google Authentication in my test server?
What url I have to register in develop console?

**Login View**

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
    {
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Login</button>
    }
```

**ExternalLogin (AccountController)**

```
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

**ExternalLoginCallback (AccountController)**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation");
    }
```

Comment: Invalid_request means there's something wrong with the request you are making.  There are several things that could be causing it.   Without seeing your Authentication code its hard to help you debug it.

Comment: @DaImTo I update source code.